# How can I formally describe the count function of the support measure of frequent itemsets

Tags: mathematical-statistics, association-measure, association-rules, apriori

currently composing a lecture on Association Rule Mining, Frequent Item sets.

Therefore I need to formally describe the count function of the support measure as occurring int the following forumula :

[image]

The count function counts the number of cases where the item set X is a subset of a transaction t occurring in the set of all transactions T

Now my question, can I mathematically (formally) describe the sentence above using the following notation?

[image]

Or if not, what would be the correct way to express this? I'm a bit concerned because "there exists" rather evaluates to Boolean and not to integer...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just asked a mathematician and this seems to be correct:

[image]